# I am not able to capture data changes with Debezium-Java

Tags: java, mysql, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm trying to make a Debezium example with Java. I want to capture this every time data is deleted in the database. When the application runs, it prints the following log on the screen:

```
Dec 10, 2022 10:18:46 PM com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient connect
INFO: Connected to localhost:3305 at binlog.000008/3443 (sid:10181, cid:41)
```

But when I delete something in the database, debezium is not able to catch it.

Connection Config Class

```
public DebeziumSignal connect(Connection data) {
    final Configuration configuration = DebeziumConfigLoader.load(data);

    engine = DebeziumEngine.create(ChangeEventFormat.of(Connect.class))
            .using(configuration.asProperties())
            .notifying(this::handleEvent)
            .build();

    return new DebeziumSignal(engine);
}
```

Config Data class:

```
public static Configuration load(Connection connection) {
    final MysqlConnection mysql = connection.getMysqlConnection();
    return Configuration.create()
            .with("name", "customer-mysql-connector")
            .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector")
            .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
            .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000")
            .with("database.hostname", mysql.getHost())
            .with("database.port", mysql.getPort())
            .with("database.user", mysql.getUsername())
            .with("database.password", mysql.getPassword())
            .with("database.dbname", mysql.getDbName())
            .with("database.include.list", String.join(",", mysql.getTables()))
            .with("include.schema.changes", "false")
            .with("database.server.id", "10181")
            .with("database.server.name", "customer-mysql-db-server")
            .with("database.history",
                    "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
            .with("database.history.file.filename",
                    "/tmp/dbhistory.dat")
            .with("database.whitelist", "mysql.*")
            .with("offset.storage.file.filename", "/tmp/offsets.dat")
            .with("table.whitelist", "mysql.*")
            .build();
}
```

connection:

```
executorService.submit(engine);
```

I expect the method named `handleEvent` to work when data is deleted from User table but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your mysql connector config has problems.

- `.with("database.include.list", String.join(",", mysql.getTables()))`: this should be in format `DB1,DB2` (Or `mysql` in you case). Or you really wanted to configure for table list, didn't you? So it should be `table.include.list=mysql.table1,mysql.table2`
- `database.whitelist` and `database.whitelist` were removed in recent Debezium versions. Now they become `database.include.list` and `database.exclude.list`

Hope these points can help you.